# Getting wrong answer with mysql date query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time, datetime-format

Here is my table

[image]

I am executing a query that give me result of fields whose `item_valid_from` must be greater than today's `date` and `item_valid_to` must be less than today.

My query is

```
select * 
  from tbl1 
 where item_valid_from >= CurDate() 
       and item_valid_to < CurDate()
```

Any Solution?

Comment: If you would store date as YYYY-MM-DD in `DATE` field, you would't have any problems...

Comment: you mean I have to modify my table structure right?

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal: if you can do that, please do it....

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal Think of the time as seconds since 1970, since this is how it is stored in unix time. That means that "item_valid_from" is going to be smaller than "item_valid_to", and you want it to display when today is somewhere between them.

Comment: @doublesharp I have just written the query it is not working in any case..

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal: OFC it isnt working! You cannot compare `YYYY-MM-DD` with `DD-MM-YYYY`... Ok, you can, but it will not work ;))

Comment: @Glavic I will try it for test server first then I will add to live one

Comment: Just a thought, avoid storing HTML in the database if you can help it. It usually indicates unsafe design decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to change `item_valid_*` field formats to `DATE` field format. You will save you a lot of trouble in the future.

But ok, if you don't want to do that, then you can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(`from_field`, '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(`to_field`, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

<kbd>[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74974f/1)</kbd>

Comment: If I change field from varchar to Date than normal query will work

Comment: Yes, then simple compare with `CURDATE()` will work. But you will need to change current data to `YYYY-MM-DD` format, before changing field format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datatype `item_valid_from` and `item_valid_to` is DATE, TIMESTAMP, etc, then you have your operators backwards. Think of the time as seconds since 1970, since this is how it is stored in unix time. That means that `item_valid_from` is going to be smaller than `item_valid_to`, and you want it to display when today is somewhere between them. You want the `item_valid_from` to be less than or equal to now, and the `item_valid_to` to be greater than now (not in the past).

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE item_valid_from <= CURDATE() AND item_valid_to > CURDATE()
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f86ee8/7) for an example, only 2-4 are valid and show up in the results being valid from a date in the past and expiring on a date in the future.

Comment: `CURDATE` is returning `YYYY-MM-DD` format. So how can you compare `DD-MM-YYYY` with `CURDATE()` ?

Comment: They are Dates, not Strings so even though they are formatted that way you still compare them as dates. Using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP might be more appropriate, check out my Sql Fiddle example.

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal At the bottom of my answer. In your table schema, what is the datatype of item_valid_from and item_valid_to? They need to be a DATE to do this comparison.

Comment: In my case it is varchar

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal I would highly recommend changing the datatype or casting it before doing comparisons then.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use following query which change current date format then compare date and fetch result :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
WHERE date_format(item_valid_from,'%d-%m-%Y') >= date_format(CurDate( ),'%d-%m-%Y')
AND date_format(item_valid_to,'%d-%m-%Y') < date_format(CurDate( ),'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Please Check this :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/561d0/2

Comment: I have updated my answer. You just change date formart in current date

Comment: it is not working your solution is wrong it is checking only d it is not working for month and year field, if I make date as 29-04-2014 it working, but for 04-04-2014 it is not working

Comment: it is not working, it only working for current month, I mean it is only matching d it is not considering month and year

Comment: @Sourabh I have Tested it in my local system . I have updated my answer please see it. Accept it.